# How to downgrade react-native dependencies?

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to Downgrade @react-native-community/async-storage, @react-native-community/masked-view, @react-navigation/native, @react-navigation/stack

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Head over to their GitHub page and choose the version you want. then you can downgrade them like this. for example the desired version is 1.1.1 so run `npm i @react-native-community/async-storage@1.1.1`. then do this for others